# What's the point of checksums inside the ruby gem

Tags: ruby, security, rubygems

So the .gem file is tarball that contains data.gz metadata.gz and checksums. Checksums are being verified before data.gz is unarchived, but I don't understand the point of this. It doesn't seem to provide any real security benefit

Comment: Are you sure every gem contains the checksums inside the tarball?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asked the maintainer, here is his answer

> I believe I encountered some errors with truncated gems that RubyGems could not detect.  Adding the checksums would allow RubyGems to determine if the gem download had completed successfully and had not been corrupted either during the download or while being cached on-disk.
>
> The checksums allow RubyGems to say “this file is corrupt” instead of a more-confusing error due to a truncated .gem (.tar) file, Zlib failure, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Normally you just run `gem install somegemfilename`  but if you chose for some reason to download the gem from https://rubygems.org/gems/ then you would want manually run the checksum on that file.

Example

Download a file like https://rubygems.org/downloads/foo-0.0.2.gem
Then in your terminal go to wherever your file is downloaded and run:

```
sha256sum foo-0.0.2.gem
# it should output the same checksum shown at https://rubygems.org/gems/foo
=> 523009a5b977f79c8eaa79b521e416f26482bc4fbbcc04bd08580696e303a715
```

That alone should be enough security.  However it seem that these are extra layers of security to insure that each gz file which are unpacked by `tar xf somegem.gem` can be individually checked against contents of `checksums.yaml` which provides several variant checksums.

Short answer is that you should not need to worry about them, but they are there for you if you want to drill down to that level.

UPDATED based on @NikitaMisharin's comment:

Yes I see your point and would tend to agree with you.  It looks like it's very old legacy Ruby code and introduced in [this commit](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/commit/9ac0e9149295f356f3aee2e6a7c3a4e22d0a904e#diff-63035a096a1484d3ccb5f311aa790dbb).

```
commit 9ac0e9149295f356f3aee2e6a7c3a4e22d0a904e
Author: Chad Fowler <chad@chadfowler.com>
Date:   Sun Nov 23 01:53:27 2003 +0000

    Generate MD5 checksum for gem and store it in the file.  Will be used to validate gem file before installation.


    git-svn-id: svn+ssh://rubyforge.org/var/svn/rubygems/trunk@66 3d4018f9-ac1a-0410-99e9-8a154d859a19
```

I would tend to conclude that this was a primitive way of checking code integrity, which has evolved since to use the checksum which would be published on [Rubygems.org](https://rubygems.org/), the standard gem repository.

I suppose this was perhaps left behind for legacy support? But I guess if you REALLY want to be sure, perhaps ask [Chad Fowler](https://github.com/chad)?

For some more background perhaps [read this documentation](http://docs.seattlerb.org/rubygems/Gem/Security.html) which is linked directly on [rubygems.org security section](https://guides.rubygems.org/security/)

Comment: I'm not sure, to be honest that this provides any extra layer of security. I mean if I get mitm attacked, checksum of the `.gem` would be enough to prevent that. But suppose I don't use bunder that checks sums automatically and I download gem directly. I don't see how someone would replace content of the gem without changing the checksums, as `gem build` also adds those checksums automatically.

Comment: @NikitaMisharin see links I've added to updated answer for more background on how or why this might be useful.

Comment: @acostenycoder I've seen the commit and docs. What surprised me is that they changed MD5 to SHA256, so it seemed like a somehow needed check. Anyway, thank you for the effort

Comment: @NikitaMisharin saw where checksum.yml also contains SHA512 hashes.